# How to add response from MySQL to Redux?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch

I've watched many tutorials on YT, and read some article about redux and fetching response, but still I don't know how to do it. My Application is developing in React. To be honest I don't even know what i'm doing, during coding this, but I try to get to know how Redux works by develop this app. I'm not natvie, so sorry for english.

This is my code, maybe someone cans help me.

types.js

```
export const FETCH_EMPTY_ROOMS = 'FETCH_EMPTY_ROOMS';
```

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { roomsReducer } from '../Reducers/reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    rooms: roomsReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

reducers.js

```
import { 
  FETCH_EMPTY_ROOMS 
} from "../Actions/types"

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  emptyRooms: []
};

export const roomsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_EMPTY_ROOMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        emptyRooms: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

actions.js

```
import { 
    FETCH_EMPTY_ROOMS
} from './types'

export const getEmptyRooms = () => dispatch => {
    return fetch('http://localhost:5000/rooms/empty_rooms')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(rooms =>
            dispatch({
              type: FETCH_EMPTY_ROOMS,
              payload: rooms
            })
        )
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
}
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import rootReducer from './Reducers/index'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools( applyMiddleware(thunk) ))

export default store;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MainTemplate from '../Templates/mainTemplate'
import Navbar from '../Components/Organism/navbar'
import Home from './home';
import Chat from './chat';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getEmptyRooms } from '../Redux/Actions/actions'


const App = ({rooms}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
      getEmptyRooms();
      console.log(rooms)
  }, [])


  return (
      <MainTemplate>
        <Router>  
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path={"/chatroom"} component={Chat} />
          </Switch>
        </Router> 
      </MainTemplate>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  rooms: state.rooms.emptyRooms
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(App);
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Redux will help you to share a common scope between multiple components.
If you want to use promise in redux you should look at [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) for example which will help you manage promise in Redux.

Another solution is to manage your request in your components.